# How to add custom Jquery in drupal module?

Tags: 7, javascript

I have created a custom module in drupal 7. The module creates a form for user and store the  form's data into database. The module is working fine. But I want to add a custom jquery for the page. I searched **Google** and find the result for adding custom JQuery for theme not for modules. I guessed and add the following in my module's  info file

```
;scripts
scripts[] = js/test.js
```

Just alert a "hello" word while the module will load. But nothing is happened. Is this possible to add custom Jquery for a module or I am doing wrong? Please help.

Comment: It should be worked if you put your code in "test.js" file in "js" directory in your current theme and then clear cache.

Comment: I did what you said and it worked. Thanks man... :)

Comment: Since it was just a problem of clearing the cache, I am going to close this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several ways of adding JS to your module, you can check them here https://www.drupal.org/node/756722

Your attempt should work fine, just don't forget to clear the caches after editing module's .info file.

Cheers!

Comment: As for reference for future answers, answers that are just links are not considered answers, on Stack Exchange. You should quote the relevant parts in the answer itself, which should not rely on an external link.

Answer (score 4):

with the drupal_add_js function you can add your own javascript file, it is best to call in hook_init

Example

```
/**
 * Implements hook_init().
 */
function mymodule_init(){
  drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/js/mymodule.script.js', array('scope' => 'footer')); 
}
```

[drupal_add_js](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7)
[hook_init](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_init/7)

This hook is not run on cached pages.
To add JS that should be present on all pages, modules should not implement this hook, but declare these files in their .info file.

```
scripts[] = js/script.js
```

Comment: From hook_init docs page: "This hook is not run on cached pages.

To add CSS or JS that should be present on all pages, modules should not implement this hook, but declare these files in their .info file."

Comment: It's done in my comment, Thx Beebee

Answer (score 1):

You can add any no of js files and css files from your .info file.
This is as simple as you modify your modulename.info file with:

```
scripts[] = js/jsfilename.js
stylesheets[all][] = css/cssfilename.css
stylesheets['specify_name'][] = css/cssfilename.css
```